# Redux store.getState() return initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I use Redux in React Native app.
I want to get the actual state outside react component

My file:

```
import memoize from 'lodash.memoize';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';
import configureStore from "../store/configureStore"

const store = configureStore();

export const translationGetters = {
    'en-US': () => require('../localizations/en.json'),
    'en-GB': () => require('../localizations/en.json'),
    'ru-RU': () => require('../localizations/ru.json'),
};

export const IMLocalized = memoize(
    (key, config) =>
        i18n.t(key, config).includes('missing') ? key : i18n.t(key, config),
    (key, config) => (config ? key + JSON.stringify(config) : key),
);

export const init = () => {
    let localeLanguageTag = Localization.locale;
    let isRTL = Localization.isRTL;
    IMLocalized.cache.clear();
    I18nManager.forceRTL(isRTL);
    i18n.translations = {
        [localeLanguageTag]: translationGetters[localeLanguageTag](),
    };
    i18n.locale = localeLanguageTag;
    getCodeLocal();
};

const getCodeLocal = () => {
    console.log('what is currently in store', store.getState())
}
```

My file configureStore.js for create store

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import SettingsReducer from "./reducers/SettingsReducer";
import SheetReducer from "./reducers/SheetReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers(
    {
        schedule: SettingsReducer,
        sheet: SheetReducer
    }
);

const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer);
}

export default configureStore;
```

After call getCodeLocal i get always initial state.
How can I get current state?

Comment: `getCodeLocal` as you wrote it there will always give you the current state or `store`.
My assumption here is that you are calling `configureStore`as well in another file, so you have two stores. You probably dispatch actions towards the other store and the store you define in this file never changes?

Comment: in ConfigureStore i create redux store. This works well in react components, but i need to get actual state after actions outside component. I check doc and saw that I could just import store file and call store.getState(). I update my question and past code configureStore.js

Comment: yes, i use const store = configureStore() in index.js file. How should I use this correctly?

Comment: only do that in once place. Export your store from your `index.js` file and import it in your `i18n` file. Don't call `configureStore` in another place as well as you will end up with two stores.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem
Thank you!